How can I provide my username and password in Memgrpah Lab 2.14?
I've updated Memgraph Lab to 2.14. Before on this screen I used to have username and passwords fields. They are gone now. How can I enter them now?
Memgraph Lab 2.14
I've tried running Memgraph using instructions from https://memgraph.com/docs/database-management/authentication-and-authorization/users#authentication but the filed is still not shown.

If you have a database configured with a username and password, after you press Connect, you will see the fields for them.


